# Flex Air Receive input when unfocused

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard, air

I am trying to find out how to continue to receive keyboard input to my app when the app is not focused. For example, if I dock my app to the system tray, is there a way to continue to receive keyboard input to be fed to the app?

Thank you in advance..
-J

Comment: Are you trying to develop key-logger in AIR :), please specify more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible since Air still runs in a runtime which can only get keyboard input on focus (as per the OS' limitation).  What you can do however is have your application ship with a native OS utility (made in C# or Java or whatever) that your Air app can communicate with and get data it needs by using `NativeProcess`.

Comment: I'll have to look further into that. Thanks